# Issue with Crashlytics and Answers kit

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using Crashlytics in my app for tracking crashes and Answers kit too for custom events. I am integrating the frameworks into my project using pod file. But I am getting a linking error while both pods are added like

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Answers'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

When I remove one from Answers and Crashlytics, then all is fine.

Error is :

> Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error Linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use to see invocation)

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here . . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001735/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error/45003900#45003900

Comment: @Roy, setting bitcode to 'No' is not working for me. Please give any other solution if you have. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Mike from Fabric here. Remove the Answers pod reference. This should be your setup for both Answers and Crashlytics.

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

If you're using Crashlytics, [Answers is included by default](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/installation.html) and that's why you're getting the conflict.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. It works. But you definitely should add the note about this (included Answers by default) at the installation doc https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/install
Users should not spend time finding this info at stack overflow

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Go to Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode to No
or Clean Xcode by ⇧⌘K (Command  Shift  K) and rebuild your project.

Comment: You try to refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: I have tried after removing framework path, but not working :(

Comment: When I am removing any one pod file then it is working fine, How can I use both 'Crashlytics' and 'Answers' in same project. Please help...