# ionic3 - Apple Mach -O Linker (Id) Error?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is the all error showing:

```
Apple Mach -O Linker (Id) Error? 
"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

[image]

After I install OneSignal plugin in my ionic3 project, haven't setup all , When I tried to run my project in my device, this error coming out.

And when I open `.xcworkspace` file, two project showing to me. First one is my real project, last one is after I install `OneSignal plugin` and install `sudo gem install cocoapods, pod repo update` then showing

[image]

Just now I tried run `ionic cordova run ios --device` that can run in my device, but when I use xcode and hit play button which cannot run in my device and showing the error that my question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to solve this error!

Because I install `pod` for push notification fucntion, so try to use the `.xcworkspace` file to run the project after pod install instead of `.xcodeproj` file.

But I still don't know why `.xcworkspace` will showing this error when I install `pod`, if you know comment here please, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1.Please install the pod file and always open with .xcworkspace.

2.Check if any files is deleted from the path (shown in red in workspace), please remove all red files.

3.Check whether files is set for the same target(if not please set all the files for the required targets).

4.Check the settings to add files.

Hope above points resolve your problem.

Comment: Do you know why hava to open with .xcworkspace?
Before I run it in .xcodeproj without error showing.

Comment: .xcworkspace is a folder of files describing the workspace and files of the projects.