# Google Consent SDK - Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, linker-errors

I'm currently trying to integrate the [Google Consent SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent), but as soon as I call

`[PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance requestConsentInfoUpdateForPublisherIdentifiers:@[ @"pub-0123456789012345"]`

I get the following error in Xcode console:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PACConsentInformation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've been searching Stackoverflow for a couple of hours now and I've tried various things such as [Enabling Bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001735/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error), [Updating Linker Flags with `$(inherited)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64?rq=1), as well as a few other things like adding suggested frameworks and `libz` found in popular questions/answers here, but still no luck.

I've gone as far to try my project in Xcode 8.3.2, Xcode 9.0 and Xcode 9.2, all of which show this error.

Is there anything I'm missing?
I'm completely stuck for ideas now.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Build Phase ->  Link Binary With Libraries then add **PersonalizedAdConsent framework**