# Ios build failed for flutter project

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-ios, flutter2.0, flutter-ios-build

```
 firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1 

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.0 at /Applications/flutter2.0_midhilaj
    • Framework revision 60bd88df91 (4 weeks ago), 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/midhilajm/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/midhilajm/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • DUB LX1 (mobile) • BVK6R19B14001142 • android-arm64  • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    ! Error: Midhilaj’s iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when Midhilaj’s iPhone is connected. (code -13)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

```
 pod install    
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing DKImagePickerController (4.3.2)
Installing DKPhotoGallery (0.0.17)
Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
Installing Firebase (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (7.9.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (7.3.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (7.3.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (8.1.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.3.1)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing SDWebImage (5.10.4)
Installing SwiftyGif (5.4.0)
Installing Toast (4.0.0)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing cloud_firestore (0.16.0-1)
Installing file_picker (0.0.1)
Installing firebase_analytics (7.0.1)
Installing firebase_auth (0.20.1)
Installing firebase_core (0.7.0)
Installing firebase_storage (7.0.0)
Installing flutter_barcode_scanner (1.0.2)
Installing flutter_inappwebview (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_pdfview (1.0.2)
Installing flutter_secure_storage (3.3.1)
Installing flutter_webview_plugin (0.0.1)
Installing fluttertoast (0.0.2)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing image_picker (0.0.1)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing libwebp (1.2.0)
Installing nanopb (2.30906.0)
Installing path_provider (0.0.1)
Installing permission_handler (4.4.0)
Installing share (0.0.1)
Installing shared_preferences (0.0.1)
Installing sqflite (0.0.1)
Installing syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer (0.0.1)
Installing url_launcher (0.0.1)
Installing video_player (0.0.1)
Installing video_thumbnail (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 23 dependencies from the Podfile and 49 total pods installed.
```

> Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view::find(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> unsigned long) const", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum::AlphaNum(absl::lts_2020_02_25::Hex)",
> referenced from: : "leveldb::WriteBatch::WriteBatch()", referenced
> from: : "leveldb::WriteBatch::Delete(leveldb::Slice const&)",
> referenced from: : "leveldb::WriteBatch::Put(leveldb::Slice const&,
> leveldb::Slice const&)", referenced from: :
> "leveldb::WriteBatch::~WriteBatch()", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrAppend(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum
> const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ChannelArguments::SetInt(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&,
> int)", referenced from: : "leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&,
> std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits,
> std::__1::allocator > const&, leveldb::DB**)", referenced from:
> : "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrAppend(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum
> const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ChannelArguments::SetSslTargetNameOverride(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&)",
> referenced from: : "leveldb::Status::Status(leveldb::Status::Code,
> leveldb::Slice const&, leveldb::Slice const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::SslCredentials(grpc_impl::SslCredentialsOptions const&)",
> referenced from: : "leveldb::Status::ToString() const", referenced
> from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::ByChar::Find(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> unsigned long) const", referenced from: :
> "grpc::ByteBuffer::Dump(std::__1::vector<grpc::Slice,
> std::__1::allocatorgrpc::Slice >*) const", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ClientContext::ClientContext()", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ChannelArguments::ChannelArguments()", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::AppendPieces(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*,
> std::initializer_listabsl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view)", referenced
> from: : "grpc::Status::OK", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::InsecureChannelCredentials()", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ClientContext::TryCancel()", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ChannelArguments::~ChannelArguments()", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ClientContext::~ClientContext()", referenced from: :
> "grpc::Version()", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::numbers_internal::FastIntToBuffer(unsigned long
> long, char*)", referenced from: : "leveldb::Options::Options()",
> referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::numbers_internal::SixDigitsToBuffer(double,
> char*)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::ClientContext::AddMetadata(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&,
> std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits,
> std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::Channel::GetState(bool)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::BytesToHexString(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view)",
> referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view::find_first_of(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> unsigned long) const", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrCat(absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::Base64Escape(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits,
> std::__1::allocator >*)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrAppend(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc::g_core_codegen_interface", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::numbers_internal::FastIntToBuffer(long long,
> char*)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::CEscape(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view)",
> referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrReplaceAll(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> std::initializer_list<std::__1::pair<absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view> >)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::numbers_internal::FastIntToBuffer(int, char*)",
> referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::CreateCustomChannelImpl(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&,
> std::__1::shared_ptr<grpc_impl::ChannelCredentials> const&,
> grpc_impl::ChannelArguments const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc::g_glip", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void**, bool*,
> gpr_timespec)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::optional_internal::throw_bad_optional_access()",
> referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrAppend(std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum
> const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)", referenced from: :
> "grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::Shutdown()", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::numbers_internal::FastIntToBuffer(unsigned int,
> char*)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::CatPieces(std::initializer_listabsl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view)",
> referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrCat(absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum
> const&)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::base_internal::ThrowStdOutOfRange(char
> const*)", referenced from: :
> "absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrCat(absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&,
> absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum
> const&, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)", referenced from: :
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: flutter ios build failed]

Comment: Lots of solutions for different scenarios here, did you check them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001735/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error

Comment: yes,   i set Enable Bitcode to No .